# Find and Replace RegEx with wildcard search and addition of value

Tags: c#, regex, replace, find, wildcard

The below code is from my other questions that I have asked here on SO.  Everyone has been so helpful and I almost have a grasp with regards to RegEx but I ran into another hurdle.

This is what I basically need to do in a nutshell.  I need to take this line that is in a text file that I load into my content variable:

**X17.8Y-1.Z0.1G0H1E1**

I need to do a wildcard search for the X value, Y value, Z value, and H value.   When I am done, I need this written back to my text file (I know how to create the text file so that is not the problem).

**X17.8Y-1.G54G0T2

G43Z0.1H1M08**

I have code that the kind users here have given me, except I need to create the T value at the end of the first line, and use the value from the H and increment it by 1 for the T value.  For example:

**X17.8Y-1.Z0.1G0H5E1**

would translate as:

**X17.8Y-1.G54G0*T6*

G43Z0.1H5M08**

The T value is 6 because the H value is 5.

I have code that does everything (does two RegEx functions and separates the line of code into two new lines and adds some new G values).  But I don't know how to add the T value back into the first line and increment it by 1 of the H value.  Here is my code:

```
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fDialog.FileName.ToString());
  string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
  reader.Close();

  content = Regex.Replace(content, @"X[-\d.]+Y[-\d.]+", "$0G54G0");
  content = Regex.Replace(content, @"(Z(?:\d*\.)?\d+)[^H]*G0(H(?:\d*\.)?\d+)\w*", "\nG43$1$2M08"); //This must be created on a new line
```

This code works great at taking:

**X17.8Y-1.Z0.1G0H5E1**

and turning it into:

**X17.8Y-1.G54G0

G43Z0.1H5M08**

but I need it turned into this:

**X17.8Y-1.G54G0*T6*

G43Z0.1H5M08**

(notice the T value is added to the first line, which is the H value +1 (T = H + 1).

Can someone please modify my RegEx statement so I can do this automatically?  I tried to combine my two RegEx statements into one line but I failed miserably.

***Update1***:  Stephen in the comments below suggests, "there's no arithmetic operators in regex, you'll need to use a group to pull out the H value, turn it into an int, add one and build a new string.".  But I have no idea on how to do this in C# code.

Comment: there's no need to put "C#" in the title since you've got it in the tags. Also, C# has no regular expression support, so a question about "C# Regex" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no arithmetic operators in regex, you'll need to use a group to pull out the H value, turn it into an int, add one and build a new string.

Comment: @Stephen How would I do this in code?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with a simple program that uses a few Regex patterns that capture (named) groups, I had a little spare time so here you go:

### Program.cs

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string InputFileName = @"input.txt";
            const string OutputFileName = @"output.txt";

            List<Line> parsedLineList = new List<Line>();

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(InputFileName))
            {
                string inputLine;
                int lineNum = 0;

                while ((inputLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    lineNum++;

                    Line parsedLine = new Line(inputLine);

                    if (parsedLine.IsMatch)
                    {
                        parsedLineList.Add(parsedLine);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Line {0} did not match pattern {1}", lineNum, inputLine);
                    }
                }
            }

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(OutputFileName))
            {
                foreach (Line line in parsedLineList)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(line.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With *input.txt* containing:

**X17.8Y-1.Z0.1G0H1E1**

this program creates *output.txt* containing:

**X17.8Y-1.G54G0T2
G43Z0.1H1M08**

The above code in Program.cs requires the following simple Line and Fragment class definitions:

### Line.cs

```
namespace Fragments
{
    class Line
    {
        private readonly static Regex Pattern =
            new Regex(@"^(?<X>X[^Y]+?)(?<Y>Y[^Z]+?)(?<Z>Z[^G]+?)(?<G>G[^H]+?)(?<H>H[^E]+?)(?<E>E[^$])$");

        public readonly string OriginalText;

        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return this.X.ToString() + this.Y.ToString() + this.G54.ToString() + this.G.ToString() + this.T.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                       this.G43.ToString() + this.Z.ToString() + this.H.ToString() + this.M08.ToString();
            }
        }

        public readonly bool IsMatch;

        public Fragment X { get; set; }
        public Fragment Y { get; set; }
        public readonly Fragment G54 = new Fragment("G54");
        public Fragment G { get; set; }
        public Fragment T { get; set; }
        public readonly Fragment G43 = new Fragment("G43");
        public Fragment Z { get; set; }
        public Fragment H { get; set; }
        public readonly Fragment M08 = new Fragment("M08");
        public Fragment E { get; set; }

        public Line(string text)
        {
            this.OriginalText = text;
            Match match = Line.Pattern.Match(text);
            this.IsMatch = match.Success;

            if (match.Success)
            {
                this.X = new Fragment(match.Groups["X"].Value);
                this.Y = new Fragment(match.Groups["Y"].Value);
                this.G = new Fragment(match.Groups["G"].Value);
                this.Z = new Fragment(match.Groups["Z"].Value);
                this.H = new Fragment(match.Groups["H"].Value);
                this.E = new Fragment(match.Groups["E"].Value);

                this.T = new Fragment('T', this.H.Number + 1.0);
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

### Fragment.cs

```
namespace Fragments
{
    class Fragment
    {
        private readonly static Regex Pattern =
            new Regex(@"^(?<Letter>[A-Z]{1})(?<Number>.+)$");

        public readonly string Text;
        public readonly bool IsMatch;

        public readonly char Letter;
        public readonly double Number;

        public Fragment(string text)
        {
            this.Text = text;
            Match match = Fragment.Pattern.Match(text);
            this.IsMatch = match.Success;

            if (match.Success)
            {
                this.Letter = match.Groups["Letter"].Value[0];
                string possibleNumber = match.Groups["Number"].Value;

                double parsedNumber;
                if (double.TryParse(possibleNumber, out parsedNumber))
                {
                    this.Number = parsedNumber;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Couldn't parse double from input {0}", possibleNumber);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Fragment {0} did not match fragment pattern", text);
            }
        }

        public Fragment(char letter, double number)
        {
            this.Letter = letter;
            this.Number = number;
            this.Text = letter + number.ToString();
            this.IsMatch = true;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Create a new C# Console Application project, add these three files, update your using statements and you're ready to go.  You can very easily alter the code in Program.cs to read the input and output filenames from Main's command line arguments to make the program reusable.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do this for me.  I appreciate it greatly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do this just with Regular Expressions, and even in case you can, thinking on maintainability of the code, I wouldn't implement it that way. What you can easily do with RegEx, is to capture the pieces you need into groups, and from those create the output expression.
Here's the code for that:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder content = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(fDialog.FileName.ToString()))
{
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        var matchingExpression = Regex.Match(line, @"(X[-\d.]+)(Y[-\d.]+)(Z(?:\d*\.)?\d+)[^H]*G0H((?:\d*\.)?\d+)\w*");

        content.AppendFormat(
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0}{1}G54G0T{2}\n",
            matchingExpression.Groups[0].Value,
            matchingExpression.Groups[1].Value,
            Int32.Parse(matchingExpression.Groups[3].Value) + 1);
        content.AppendFormat(
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "G43{0}H{1}M08\n", 
            matchingExpression.Groups[2].Value, 
            matchingExpression.Groups[3].Value);

        line = reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

And to get the output string you should do:

```
content.ToString();
```

Comment: At quick glance of your code I don't see where you are adding the T value back to the end of G54G0 (ex G54G0T6; if H is H5).  Thanks.

Comment: I could not get your code to execute correctly.  It had errors such as 'string' does not contain a definition for AppendLine.  The same error for AppendFormat, and CultureInfo does not exist in the current context.

Comment: AppendLine and AppendFormat are methods of StringBuilder class not string (which is the type of "content" on my code snippet). To use it and CultureInfo, you should add "using System.Text;" and "using System.Globalization;" on top of the .cs file (without the quotes obviously). Also, you're right about the T value, I misplaced the regular expression that captures and add 1 to its value (it's on the second line in my code snippet). I'll recreate the regular expression later and correct the snippet.